# How to set favicon icon in PHP restapi file

Tags: php, favicon

I want to set a favicon icon on this page, but I cannot do it by `echo` because the `PHP` is going to `echo` out `JSON` format. How do I do it?

if I add this line It is mixing up with my main output

```
echo '<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">';
```

the output I'm getting

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">hello world
```

my `PHP` code

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

class Main {
    function mFun() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}

$main = new Main();
echo '<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">';
$main -> mFun();

?>
```

**UPDATE**

why anyone not noticing `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: it can be done, just make sure you put favicon.ico in the same directory as ur php and remove the slash /

Comment: Add a favicon to the root of your API request url. You don't need to add `link` include

Comment: By doing that I'm getting `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` with my json

Comment: @JackNicholson can you elaborate with code?

Comment: @Arghadip Sorry for the late reply, What I meant is that if you are trying to return JSON data with a favicon then the favicon will be taken from the root of your site automatically by some browsers. (Latest chrome does currently do this). You don't need to return the favicon in your page at all with any code. Simply have `/favicon.ico` in your root. I hope this helps you :) IF you are trying to change a favicon then you need to wait for cache to expire. It will happen in time, you won't be able to clear the cache for it

Comment: Not all browsers will pull the favicon. It will depend on your browser. Hopefully this helps - I don't know why this was closed with a useless 'duplicate' thread. Had nothing to do with JSON requests...